# Return the tuple in sql query result if it occures more than a predefine number (like 5).

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, row-number

I have a lots of lots of rows made by joining different tables. I would like to write a query that it returns the current rows if and only if the number of rows bigger than a specific number like 5 otherwise returns nothing. I know that I can do it pragmatically but is there any way to do it  in sql server as a query.

EDIT: I chose the way that @prdp suggested. created a common table expression with row_number and select all that have rowId bigger than 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
WITH cte
     AS (SELECT *,
                Row_number()
                  OVER (
                    ORDER BY id) AS rowid
         FROM   <tablename>)
SELECT *
FROM   cte
WHERE  EXISTS(SELECT 1
              FROM   cte
              WHERE  rowid >= 5)
```

Comment: Thank you. I got the idea. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use window functions:

```
with t as (
      <your query here>
     )
select t.*
from (select t.*, count(*) over () as cnt
      from t
     ) t
where cnt > 5;
```

Note that any `order by` clauses should be in the outer query, not the CTE (unless you are using `TOP`, in which case the `order by` should be in both places).

Comment: isn't it return data with rows bigger than 5? I don't want it. I would like to return it if at least 5 rows are available.

Comment: @vagueness . . . This returns results only if at least five rows are in the result set, which seems to be what your question is asking for.